¿Cómo puedo reescribir este comando shell para llamar a PowerShell sólo una vez, y aún así leer mi archivo Yaml en mi Makefile?
Introducción
Estoy usando el comando shell de Makefile para leer un archivo YAML, pero el problema que tengo es que al ejecutar es muy lento.
Problema
Se debe de invocar 4 veces al shell para leer el archivo YAML lo cual es muy costoso en términos de ejecución.
Objetivo
Quiero minimizar el uso del shell a una sola llamada y configurar el resto de variables del Makefile
Código actual
AS := $(shell powershell "(Get-Content -Path "config.yaml" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Yaml).assembly.assembler")
LD := $(shell powershell "(Get-Content -Path "config.yaml" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Yaml).assembly.linker")
ASFLAGS := $(shell powershell "(Get-Content -Path "config.yaml" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Yaml).assembly.asflags")
LDFLAGS := $(shell powershell "(Get-Content -Path "config.yaml" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Yaml).assembly.ldflags")

Actualmente este código hace lo que quiero, pero es lento ya que debe llamarse al shell 4 veces y leer el archivo YAML 4 veces
Datos extra
Estoy usando el modulo powershell-yaml para leer el archivo YAML

Exactamente ... ¿ A cuento de qué viene lo de Sarcasmo ? Te garantizo que así no vas a conseguir mas respuestas. Yo mismo, esté o no capacitado para responderte, no le voy a dedicar mas tiempo a tu pregunta en cuanto termine de escribir este comentario.

una posible solucion seria:
ASSEMBLY_VARS := $(shell powershell -Command "\
  $$config = Get-Content -Path 'config.yaml' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Yaml; \
  \"AS=$$($${config}.assembly.assembler)`n\" + \
  \"LD=$$($${config}.assembly.linker)`n\" + \
  \"ASFLAGS=$$($${config}.assembly.asflags)`n\" + \
  \"LDFLAGS=$$($${config}.assembly.ldflags)\" \
")


$(eval $(ASSEMBLY_VARS))

